# Python script to get file path: insert the result inside quotes; I get the full path but not quotes

Tags: python, python3

I have a python script which copy the full path of text files opened in gedit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import sys

name = subprocess.check_output(["xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowname"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
if all(["(" in name, ")" in name]):
    path = name[name.find("(")+1:name.find(")")]
    if sys.argv[1] == "-file":
        fname = name[:name.find("(")]
    elif sys.argv[1] == "-path":
        fname = ""
    command = f"echo \"{path}/{fname}\" | tr -d '\\n' | sed 's/.$//' | xclip -selection clipboard"
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
```

But the result is not surrounded with quotes: I get `/path/to/file` instead of `"path/to/file"`

How should I edit the script to get the result inside quotes?

Comment: Add them before piping to clipboard, something like `sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/'`

Comment: @Panki I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 0):

I've got what I need using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname | grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+')
path2="${path/#\~/$HOME}"
filename=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname | cut -d"(" -f1 | rev | cut -c2- | rev)


echo "\"$path2/$filename"\" | tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection clipboard
```

I exactly got the full path to the text file, surrounded with quotes, eg:

```
"/home/dave/Documents/text file"
```